# IntelliJ showing slow parameter hints

Tags: intellij-idea, parameters, intellij-14, hints

Hi is there any way where i can speed up the parameter hints animation - the one where it pops up in a bubble form while typing out the parameters?

Comment: Do you have it slow with the [last version](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download)? Could you record a screen cast that would show it?

Comment: this is the first version im using for Intellij , but based on tutorials that i have viewed, the popup animation hint was much faster, almost immediate, compared to mine